# Cannot copy from ubuntu 16.04 virtualbox guest and paste to windows 7 host via RDP

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, windows-7, remote-desktop, clipboard

I have a virtualbox guest running (k)ubuntu 16.04 on a Windows 7 professional host, using VirtualBox version 5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.6.2), guest additions installed. The guest has bidirectional clipboard enabled, and, on ubuntu itself, I have installed parcellite clipboard manager. If I open the guest and use it directly (using the "Start...Normal Start" option), I can copy and paste from host to guest and from guest to host, no problem.  But if I start headless and use rdp, I can only copy from the host to the guest, not vice versa. (In both scenarios I can copy from host to host and guest to guest.)  I have "Clipboard" checked under "Local Resources...Local Devices and resources" in the RDP options.

RDP may be the only option for connecting to guests in the near future (as we are moving our VM's to a central, dedicated box), so I would like to get this to work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: More info. If I start "direct" (Vbox Start...Normal Start), the clipboard works both ways. If I then connect thru rdp, clipboard from guest to host stops working, even after I kill the rdp session and use the (still running) direct session.  I have to restart the VM and only use it "directly" (not sure what else to call it) in order to get both directions working again.

Comment: Did you install the Guest Additions CD in the VM?

Comment: @Terrance yes, the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso is showing in the Controller: IDE slot in Settings...Storage.

Comment: Did you run the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` installer from the `/media/username/VBOXADDITIONS_#.#.##_######` folder in the VM to install the utilities to allow for shared clipboard as well?

Comment: Just did that, it all went well, and I then restarted the vm.  Connecting via RDP, same problem :(